# PDO Attributes on symfony doctrine bundle configuration

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

My question is simple as the solution is hard to find. :')

I want to add some [PDO attributes](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.setattribute.php) on the doctrine/dbal configuration for Symfony2.

Where can I put this attributes?

Answer (score -2):

With DoctrineBundle, you can use the [options](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration) settings.

#### Edit

@JTG you're right, this was answered to quickly without enough informations.

About the `ATTR` constant, you have two choice:

- First use the numerical value of the constant (not really portable code but works)
- Second is to define your doctrine config using the XML format and take advantage of [Constants as parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#constants-as-parameters)

Try something like this (not tested):

```
<!-- app/config/doctrine.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:doctrine="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/doctrine"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/doctrine
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/doctrine/doctrine-1.0.xsd"
>
<parameters>
    <parameter key="global.pdo.attr_case" type="constant">PDO::ATTR_CASE</parameter>
    <parameter key="global.pdo.case_lower" type="constant">PDO::CASE_LOWER</parameter>
</parameters>

<doctrine:config>
    <doctrine:dbal
        driver="%database_driver%"
        host="%database_host%"
        dbname="%database_name%"
        user="%database_user%"
        password="%database_password%"
    >
        <doctrine:option key="%global.pdo.attr_case%">%global.pdo.case_lower%</doctrine:option>
</doctrine:config>
</container>
```

Comment: Yes I saw this documentation.

But it isn't really clear, how I put the `ATTR` constant inside it ?

foo/bar is not really relevant.